# Chinese file name when compiling in Lyx

Tags: lyx

When the file is named with Chinese characters, the Lyx will compile the Chinese character as '__'. It looks the Chinese characters are not compiled correctly. I would like to know if it is a method to make it print normally?

for example, the file "test中文.lyx" will transformed as "test____.pdf".

Comment: You can print chinese character by unicode encoding Details : https://www.programmersought.com/article/26805540709/

Comment: @KayesFahim The link shows access denied. The contents with Chinese characters are compiled well. The problem is on the Chinese file name, which is not compiled correctly, showing as undersorces shown above.

Comment: you have to use vpn for access page and use unicode converted for file name reading and convert it on english.